# JRE 8 with JDK 7 installation

Tags: jvm, java-8

Due to system needs we want to have JDK 7 with JRE 8. So i installed JRE 8 alone on my system. But do i have to delete JRE 7 from `C:\Program Files\Java`. Can anyone suggest a proper setup steps.

Comment: No, its not requried. You can work on lower versions, if you have the higher. All you need is to install JDK 8 and while in your project setup, use jdk7 from project facets.

Comment: is it JDK 8 or JDK 7 am confused. My installation has the following 3 folders jdk1.7.0_79, jre1.8.0_51. jre7. so which JRE will be used?

Comment: Just go for JDK8, and after your project setup use jdk7 from project facets.
Right Click On Project --> Properties --> Project Facets --> Change JAVA to 1.7 there.

Comment: Leave alone eclipse from comand prompt if i want to run on jre8 and jdk7 then with the current installation will it work? I have set the JAVA_HOME to JDK7 only....and since JRE7 and JRE8 both are there which one will be taken...